# MPI null address in fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

Imagine summing the values of a variable `var_to_be_summed` via  `MPI_REDUCE` to a `buffer` on `root=0`.

```
call MPI_REDUCE(var_to_be_summed, buffer, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
```

According to [MPICH](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) the `buffer` is *only significant on root*. So in principle I could use any variable. For example in cases where the `buffer` is not natively present on the non-root ranks.

```
real :: dummy
if(rank==root) then 
  call MPI_REDUCE(var_to_be_summed, buffer, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
else
  call MPI_REDUCE(var_to_be_summed, dummy, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_SUM, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, err)
endif
```

My question is: Is there a nice/generic/standard way (in terms of portability, easy coding and reading) of giving a null-like argument to MPI routines with an "non significant" buffer on the non-root ranks.

I thought of replacing `dummy` in the code above with [`MPI_BOTTOM`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/Constants.html) since it represents an address, but I am not sure about any side effects.

**TL;DR:**
Is there a variable supported by MPI that represents a "null" or "any" address like the generic tag  `MPI_ANY_TAG`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not natively present on the non-root ranks"? If you're in SPMD mode, then you probably have `buffer` as a variable available to use

Comment: In my case I have (quite complex and nested) derived types in a master/slave scenario. Some types are allocated only on the master. If I want a member of a type only allocated on the master to be the buffer, I run into the above "problem".

Comment: Using `MPI_IN_PLACE` is not exactly what you want, but it does make it possible to skip having any variable one argument. Of course be careful on the root. I'll note that the MPL C++ interface allows a polymorphic `MPI_Reduce` where non-root processes only specify the send buffer. Maybe you can extend the `INTERFACE` block for `MPI_Reduce` in Fortran to allow that?

Comment: So you have implemented a custom `MPI_REDUCE` operation on your derived type? Is it the same buffer used for many different lines of code? One way that comes to mind for me is a pointer of the derived type - it could point to the valid buffer on root and to null on non-root.

Comment: Related to what Ross is saying in comparable situations I have allocated the variables to size zero on processes where they are not needed. This is not ideal, as you lose the distinction between being of size 0 and simply not existing, but does tend to simplify the code

Comment: I am not convinced `MPI_IN_PLACE` is allowed on non root rank(s).

Comment: @Ross I have no custom ```MPI_REDUCE``` and this situation arises only occasionally in my code.

Comment: Thanks for the input! For your answers it seems there is no such thing as a MPI variable for a null address. That basically answers my question. The workarounds suggested by Ross and IanBush  are nice, although they need some extra lines of code.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet `MPI_IN_PLACE` is allowed but it's tricky: on the root you specify it for the send buffer, on non-root processes you specify it for the receive buffer.

Comment: @VictorEijkhoutwell, since this argument is ignored on non root ranks, it could be pretty much anything (except a non allocated array because Fortran prohibits it) including `MPI_IN_PLACE` :-). The `0` constant could also do the trick.